# How to share the files (files object) between the various processes in python?

Tags: python-3.x, process, multiprocessing, synchronization, file-locking

I'm implementing the multiprocessing, there are lot of JSON files, I want  to read and write those files by various processes, I'm doing multiprocessing. I don't want the race condition in between so I also want the processes needs to be synchronised there.

I'm trying the following dummy code. But I don't know why it is not working I'm using multiprocess Queue to share the open file object. Could you guys suggest me is there anything wrong I'm doing, i'm getting error,  I'm new to multiprocessing stuff.
Below is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Lock

def writeTofile(q, lock, i):

  
    print(f'some work by {i}')
    text = f" Process {i} -- "
    ans =""
    for i in range(10000):
        ans += text
    
    #critiacl section 
    lock.acquire()
    file = q.get() 
    q.put(file)
    file.write(ans)
    lock.release()

    print(f'updated by process {i}')


def main():
    q = Queue()
    lock = Lock()
    jobs = []
    with open("test.txt", mode = 'a') as file:
        q.put(file)
        for i in range(4):
            process = Process(target = writeTofile, args = (q, lock, i))
            jobs.append(process)
            process.start()

        
        for j in jobs:
            j.join()



    print('completed')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the error I'm getting below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akshaysingh/Desktop/ipnb/multi-processing.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/akshaysingh/Desktop/ipnb/multi-processing.py", line 27, in main
    q.put(file)
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 808, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

Comment: `for j in process` is a problem as `process` is a `Process()` not a list of `Process()`

Comment: my bad yeah it was typo from my side that should be the jobs, since I'm storing the processes inside the jobs. let me update this Thanks @JonSG. But still error persist

Comment: You can't really share open file handles easily. Just have a shared lock, and open and close the file by filename: `with lock(): with open(filename): write_file`

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. So is this platform independent ? i.e. it will also works with linux OS, MacOS, and Windows.

Comment: @AkshaySingh yes. Under the hood, [`multiprocessing.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) is implemented by the OS, but python provides a common interface that pretty much always works the same way.

Comment: To be clear, it may be possible to share an open handle, but it's more difficult / OS dependent. Passing the file name as a string, and passing a lock is much easier in my opinion.